# Facebook "Like" produces "There was an internal error when updating the Page."

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-like

I added a like button to my blog a few months ago and things have been working perfectly.  Suddenly I added a new post this morning, and for whatever reason, the like button is now broken.  Everytime I click "Like" I receive this error:

```
There was an internal error when updating the Page.
```

There is no additional information.

I used Facebook's LINT and the meta info comes through perfectly, only the same vague error appears:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.alifewortheating.com%2Fparis%2Flambroisie-revisited

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Has anyone experienced this before?

Thank you!

Comment: Here is a link to the blog post that produces this error: http://www.alifewortheating.com/paris/lambroisie-revisited

Answer (score 1):

for me helped removing **meta**-tag with property="**og:type**".
Earlier it was on my page:

> <meta property="og:type" content="product"/>

As referring to this page (like btn section):
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/

> If you’re interested in gaining
>   distribution for content or giving
>   users the ability to like a virtual
>   good, you should not include the
>   og:type tag. In this case, a stream
>   story will still be published when
>   your users like your content, but your
>   URL will not be equivalent to a
>   Facebook page. This means you will not
>   have the ability to publish to users,
>   and your pages will not show up on
>   users' profiles.
>
> If your canvas URL represents a
>   real-world object (e.g. a cause,
>   movie, product), add the appropriate
>   og:type tag. In this case your canvas
>   URL will be equivalent to a Facebook
>   page. In addition to stream
>   distribution, when a user likes your
>   page you will have the ability to
>   publish updates to them, and your URL
>   will show up on users' profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook, last I checked, requires the `og:admins`  `<meta>` property.

Comment: I tried adding that in but it didn't make a difference.  Also I have the app_id property set, which should be sufficient, no?

Comment: app_id should be sufficient, yes. I just realized that I have my meta tags commented out on my blog and it still allowing people to like it. Maybe try that? haha