# facebook like button won't "like"

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like

So what's strange is that the like buttons on my site will only work IF the like button has already been liked in the past. If there are no current likes, such as on this page:

http://www.narutomeetsbleach.com/naruto-shippuden-219.html

Then you can click like all you want, but you won't actually like anything. Does anyone know what's wrong? I got my like HTML directly from facebook and it's the exact same as the like buttons that are working.

Thanks so much!

Comment: You'll have to complain to Facebook.  The button and all it's code comes from them and it's within an iframe with source from their server... you'll have no control over how that works.

Comment: okay. just wasn't sure if I was doing something wrong.

Comment: Just double-check your tags making sure you got your App ID and such entered correctly... otherwise, you're at their mercy.

Comment: actually, I don't think that I ever created an app for this but it worked fine. I have to create an app just to have the like button?

Comment: Contrary to what you may think, you'll need to create your unique App Id for a simple "Like" button (XFBML version).  See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out! I had to remove the og:type meta tag. Found someone else on google who had a similar problem, that's what he did and now it seems to be working fine for me after I re-linted the url. Facebook's giving me a "warning" because I have og:type missing, but now it's working, so I guess that's all that matters. Thanks for all the help!

reference: [Facebook "Like" produces "There was an internal error when updating the Page."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006213/facebook-like-produces-there-was-an-internal-error-when-updating-the-page)

Comment: For me it worked the other way around. I added the og:type property and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Facebook LINT tool. It actually checks you meta tags and will point you in some direction what your problem is. (Check link below.. I have added a `?v=1` to the html page to avoid facebook server error response)

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.narutomeetsbleach.com%2Fnaruto-shippuden-219.html%3Fv%3D1

Type in your url and check your page.

Try changing your code to the following (is there a reason why you are using the appId/fbAsyncInit methods?):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div><script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://www.narutomeetsbleach.com/naruto-shippuden-219.html?v=2" send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false" font="tahoma"></fb:like>
```

**AND / OR**

Use this link to generate your LIKE BUTTON Code

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Generated Like Button Code (Iframe) :

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=137084976372144&amp;href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.narutomeetsbleach.com%2Fnaruto-shippuden-219.html%3Fv%3D3&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Comment: hmmm...it says that there was an internal error, but it doesn't tell me what :/

Comment: Check my updated answer, please let me know once updated, so I can check the Lint response.

Comment: I changed my html tag. Is that all you wanted me to do?

Comment: what's strange is http://www.narutomeetsbleach.com/naruto-shippuden-220.html also won't work, yet the lint thing says that there are no errors with that.

Comment: Very strange indeed. I have updated my answer again. The html code is the code I used not so long ago on my own project. It's currently working..only difference is that I had SEND set to false. Let me know if it works.

Comment: okay, I made that change. Even with the v=2 at the end, then I could like older pages before when I didn't have the problem, I could like those individually even though they didn't have any likes anymore, but the newer ones (219 and 220) still have the same issue :/

Comment: should I also set send equal to false?

Comment: does my app id for my comments box and like button need to be different? do I need two separate "apps"?

Comment: I was looking back and I can like pages that have no likes as long as they have been up on my site for a while. It's almost as if only recent pages aren't working. Maybe facebook has changed something and cached these pages wrong? Not sure.

Comment: Yeah, one never knows when facebook makes changes. I had a FB Application problem the other day by using a normal HTML page, instead of a PHP or a .Net page... it maybe that? Unsure.

Comment: Found it out! I had to remove the og:type meta tag. Found someone else on google who had a similar problem, that's what he did and now it seems to be working fine for me after I re-linted the url. Facebook's giving me a "warning" because I have og:type missing, but now it's working, so I guess that's all that matters. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Great stuff! Glad you managed, I will definitely remember this for future reference. :)

Comment: Yeah, I'm glad I figured it out, but the pages only seem to work now if I relint them manually first! It's the weirdest thing.

Comment: Actually, the only way it'll let me like anything is if I lint the page first. Even if I add a new page, it's the exact same problem until I lint it! Any ideas with that?

Comment: @Adam:  See my answer... you definitely need an App Id; even for just a Like button.

Comment: Lint'ing a page before the Like button works is very strange, maybe Facebook is updating again? One will never know. Sparky672, I have never added an appID to add a Like button to my pages, what I know is that a meta-admins is now necessary so that the Like count can show properly.

Comment: @Marc:  What you say makes total sense.  However, for the XFBML version (at least for the Like Box), an App Id was required before mine would properly load and function.  See my answer which links to the FB developer docs... XFBML uses the JavaScript SDK which requires an App Id.

Answer (score -1):

The Facebook button and all it's code comes from them and it's within an iframe with source from their server... you'll have little control over how that works.  As long as you got your App ID and such entered correctly... otherwise, you're at their mercy.

Yes, even though it's just a "Like" button, you still need an App ID (appid).  More detailed info below...

See the accepted answer to this: ["Do I need an appid for the XFBML version of the Facebook Like button?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574443/do-i-need-an-appid-for-a-xfbml-version-of-the-facebook-like-button)

And quoting this page, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/:

*"The JavaScript SDK **requires that you register your website with Facebook to get an App ID** (or appId). The appId is a unique identifier for your site that ensures that we have the right level of security in place between the user and your website. The following example shows how to load the JavaScript SDK once you have your appId:"*